# How to know document.forms['aspnetForm'].submit() make the submit at the server side?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I use

```
document.forms['aspnetForm'].submit()
```

to submit the form. There are other buttons doing some other things at the server side too.

Is it possible at the server side, e.g, in Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e), use some method to check client side called this

```
document.forms['aspnetForm'].submit()
```

?

thanks

================more explain===================

for example, clicking either button below will submit the form to server side, how do I know which one is clicked in Page_Load?

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="document.forms['aspnetForm'].submit()" />
<input type="submit" value="Edit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a value in a `hidden` field at the same time you call the `.submit()` in your JavaScript. Like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="client-submit" value="true" />
```

(Then check for that form-field value on the server-side.)

Comment: it is a little complicated since I will also need to set the value back to false when the page returns from the server side... hope there are other ways doing it...

Comment: If the default value of that hidden field is false, it will return to false when the page reloads.